# Google Visualization library not loading with Rails 3.2 and coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I'm attempting to use the Google Visualization library in a Rails 3.2 application.  I have the following in my application.html.erb

```
<head>
 <title>Website</title>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
 <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

I have the following in my stuff.js.coffee:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', packages: ['gauge'])
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)
drawChart ->
  data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Memory', 80],
    ['CPU', 55],
    ['Network', 68]
  ])
  options = {
    width: 400, height: 120,
    redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
    yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
    minorTicks: 5
  }
  chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('result'))
  chart.draw(data, options)
```

I'm getting a js error when the page loads: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

If I move the chart setup/creation js up into the application.hmtl.erb it all works.  Something is obviously not getting loaded in the right order here.

Answer (score 1):

Try including Google's jsapi file *before* application.js

```
<head>
 <title>Website</title>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
 <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

I saw this solution in [this github issue](https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker/issues/10#issuecomment-5455408) and it worked for me.